# MDL + jQuery validate integration: Work-around needed for mdl-radio__button validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, material-design-lite

What would seem to be a normal use-case of jQuery.validate with MDL has gone awry. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/brianthelion/5e3a7491631b7e09795e).

This works fine:

```
<h1>Without MDL</h1>
<form id="foo">
  <input type="radio" name="bar" value="1" /> 1
  <input type="radio" name="bar" value="2" /> 2
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<script>
     $(function() {
         $('#foo').validate({
             rules: {
                 "bar": {
                     required: true
                 },
             },
             errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                 console.log(element);
             }
         });
     });
</script>
```

This does *nothing*:

```
<h1>With MDL</h1>
<form id="zha">
    <label for="baz__1" class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="baz" value="1" id="baz__1" class="mdl-radio__button" /> 1
    </label>
    <label for="baz__2" class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="baz" value="2" id="baz__2" class="mdl-radio__button" /> 2
    </label>
    <input type="submit" id="butt"/>
</form>
<script>
     $(function() {
         $('#zha').validate({
             rules: {
                 "baz": {
                     required: true
                 },
             },
             errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                 console.log(element);
             }
         });
     });
</script>
```

Attaching `jQuery.validator.setDefaults({ debug: true })` has no effect -- as in *zero* debug output -- in the MDL version. Removing either `mdl-js-radio` or `mdl-radio__button` makes it work as expected. My intuition is that MDL is updating the DOM in a way that disconnects jQuery's access to `name=` attributes, but I can't find any evidence to support that in the MDL source code.

Anybody got an integration that works here?

Comment: Quote:  *"My intuition is that MDL is updating the DOM in a way that disconnects..."* ~ that's probably the case; so why not simply use any browser's DOM inspection tool and find out?

Comment: I did, but either my DOM-fu is weak or my intuition is wrong.

Comment: is it just a typo that you are not wrapping the mdl version's script in a jquery function?

Comment: Yes, typo, thanks! Will correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research, I think I found a solution to your problem. It's an interesting one.
For me, your code works on Firefox but not on Chrome and Safari. The reason is pretty simple. MDL remove the CSS default style of your input radio buttons to hide them (not display: none, only height: 0, width: 0, opacity...). Chrome and Safari consider that like there are **"hidden"**. Browsing the jQuery.validate code, I realized that the input radio buttons was never discovered. (your code works with a classic input on Chrome and safari). And why ? Because if you take a look at the default settings of jQuery.validate you can see that he ignore the input hidden.

```
defaults: {
   ...
   ignore: ":hidden",
   ...
onfocusin: function( element, event ) {
```

And the filter function

```
elements: function() {
    var validator = this,
        rulesCache = {};

    // select all valid inputs inside the form (no submit or reset buttons)
    return $(this.currentForm)
    .find("input, select, textarea")
    .not(":submit, :reset, :image, [disabled]")
    .not( this.settings.ignore ) // This line
    .filter(function() {
        if ( !this.name && validator.settings.debug && window.console ) {
            console.error( "%o has no name assigned", this);
        }

        // select only the first element for each name, and only those with rules specified
        if ( this.name in rulesCache || !validator.objectLength($(this).rules()) ) {
            return false;
        }

        rulesCache[this.name] = true;
        return true;
    });
},
```

To prevent this just add this piece of code :

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: ""
});
```

It works for me. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Nice sleuthing! I'll double-check your work shortly.

Comment: Tks. Finally, it was not a big deal. Hope it helped you.